# Hive inserting max+1 into same table not working

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

i have a scenario ...

i have a table called **sample** with three columns:

```
id, name, address
```

where id is a unique auto increment column. here is my data:

id   name   address
1    john    LA
2    peter.  VS

my next column would be `3, 'smith', 'vegas'`

i tried like this:

```
insert into sample select c1 as id from (select max(id)+1 from sample) c1, 'smith' as name , 'vegas' as address;
```

getting `Error: Error compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Error in parsing (sttae=402000,code=40000)`

i have tried for udf for auto increment column but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Hive (alas) doesn't support auto-increments.  You can implement this as:

```
insert into sample (id, name, address)
    select coalesce(max(id) + 1, 1), 'smith' as name , 'vegas' as address
    from sample c1;
```

That said, I strongly recommend that you don't do this.  Two `insert`s running at the same time will (likely) see the same maximum value -- and insert the same value for the id.  To get around this, you would need to lock the entire table for each insert.  And that is quite expensive.

Use UUIDs and an insertion date instead.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a syntax thing. since i dont have a hive instance to try out,

does this work?

```
  insert 
    into sample 
  select max(id)+1 c1
        ,max('smith') as name 
        ,max('vegas') as address
   from sample
```

Comment: not working. i have updated my question please have a look.

Comment: If it's a auto increment column why do u need the max + 1 logic. You are guaranteed non overlapping numbers all the time.

Comment: its is not auto increment column, just normal column